# What's the difference between "rigor" and "rigorousness"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

What's the difference between rigor and rigorousness?

Which should I use in the following?

> Rigorousness and clarity are not synonymous in pedagogy.

Comment: In this case you should use _rigor_ because it's shorter and consistent with _clarity_, which is also short. It's just a style choice in this sentence. Beyond that, what tchrist says in his answer is spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship between *rigor* and *rigorousness* is that *rigor* is similar in meaning to “severity” or “strictness”, but *rigorousness* is primarily “the abstract property of having to do with, or being inclined to, *rigor*”. As for which is best in your sentence, it simply comes down to which one you mean.

The suffixes *-ous* and *-ness* are *productive*, meaning they are used by English speakers as part of habits or “rules” for producing new words. These compound words, in the ears of English speakers, will generally mean what the individual parts mean.

The suffix *-ous* takes a noun *X* and creates an adjective *X-ous* which stands for “having *X*”, “full of *X*”, “having to do with *X*”, “doing *X*”, or “inclined to *X*”.[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ous)

- *avarice* → *avaricious* (having/full of/having to do with/doing/inclined to *avarice*)
- *beauty* → *beauteous* (having/full of/having to do with/doing/inclined to *beauty*)
- *cancer* → *cancerous* (having/full of/having to do with/doing/inclined to *cancer*)

The suffix *-ness* can take an adjective *Y* and create a noun *Y-ness* which stands for the abstract action, quality, or state which *Y* has to do with.[²](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ness) You can think of this as converting a *description* of something to a *property* which it possesses.

- *ripe* → *ripeness* (abstract action, quality, or state property from *ripe*)
- *strange* → *strangeness* (abstract action, quality, or state property from *strange*)
- *tight* → *tightness* (abstract action, quality, or state property from *tight*)

As you might expect, then, when these productive suffixes are used together with a noun *Z*, the resulting compound *Z-ous-ness* will mean “the abstract action, quality or state of having/being full of/having to do with/doing/being inclined to *Z*”. You can think of this as converting a thing to an abstract property having to do with such a thing.

- *mystery* → *mysteriousness* (the abstract property of having to do with a *mystery*)
- *number* → *numerousness* (the abstract property of having a *number*)
- *odor* → *odorousness* (the abstract property of having an *odor*)

Because these habits or “rules” of new word production are instilled into the minds of English speakers, they will find it possible to make sense of words which are invented using this method, even when the combinations have never been seen before.

- *santorum* → *santorumousness* (the abstract property of having to do with *santorum*)

Such habits or “rules” are not, of course, the whole story. Once a new word is coined by compounding with suffixes and becomes a popular word, it is tossed and buffeted by the same social forces which cause all words to evolve in meaning. The compound may acquire unique connotations which do not wholly apply to its parts. A good dictionary will provide this information.

Comment: If you were saying the original statement, would you use rigor or rigorousness?

Answer (score 7):

There are many other pairs of words like this in English, just as *joy* and *joyousness* (or *joyfulness*), or somewhat more indirectly, *pugnacity* and *pugnaciousness*.  Most of them mean the same in the longer and shorter form, but some can sometimes carry additional nuance and so do not always allow complete swapping.

In this particular case, I believe they are identical, and that you can replace *rigorousness* with *rigor* in your example sentence:

> Rigor and clarity are not synonymous in pedagogy.

However, when *rigor* means “severe”, I don’t think you can do so as easily.  For example:

> The rigourousness of the trail under blizzard conditions was a true test of the pioneer spirit.

I really don’t think you can swap that one the way you can with your own example.

The OED defines *rigorousness* as

> Rigorous action, procedure, or temper; rigour.

And *rigorous* has in turn several senses of its own. One of these is very strict and exacting, but another is very harsh weather.   I think only the first swaps for *rigor* very easily.

Comment: You mean rigor can't mean harshness of weather bug rigorousness can?

Comment: @Problemania Can’t is a strong word. But maybe. Rigorous goes both ways, but I do not know for sure about rigor itself.

Comment: *Rigor* does indeed have among its meanings a sense of “severity (of living conditions)”.

Comment: @MετάEd That would be “the rigors of the trail”, not “the rigor of the trail”.  Note plural.

Comment: Surely you mean, "when *rigorous* means “severe”"?

Comment: @tchrist For example, I find "rigor of the battlefield" in Google Book Search. "Rigors" (pl.) may be more common, but "rigor" (sing.) undeniably is used also.

Answer (score 1):

*Rigorousness* is a general word that can be applied in any context.

***Rigor*** is an established term used in the pedagogical field, and in its critique.

> ... [academic rigor](http://hechingerreport.org/content/rigor-its-all-the-rage-but-what-does-it-mean_2222/) ... “a demanding yet accessible curriculum that engenders critical-thinking skills as well as content knowledge.”

For an interesting report, see *DEFINING RIGOR IN HIGH SCHOOL: Framework and Assessment Tool* [[pdf](http://www.txechs.com/downloads/55_rigorframeworktool.pdf) 160kB]

> ... the term “rigor” in the context of high school improvement can be used as shorthand for a set of ideas, principles and strategies that lead to a desired outcome—all students are well prepared for post-secondary education, career and civic life. These ideas, principles and strategies comprise a conceptual framework to guide reform. Rigor can be talked about in terms of specific course requirements and curricula, in terms of the quality of content and instruction, and in terms of strategies to support improved student achievement.

Criticism:

> [Rigor](http://sociallynetworkeddetroit.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/5-words-ive-abolished-from-my-vocabulary/): The single-word anthem of educators everywhere. While it’s sad to know that there are people that don’t believe that educators haven’t been expecting the best out of our children all along, “rigor” seems to imply as if they’re putting our kids through boot camp.

When writing on pedagogy, never use one term for the other.